# Twitter Crawler on Python

Tags: python, api, twitter, web-crawler

I'm trying to gather tweets data from twitter using python.
This is my code.

```
#API
consumer_key = "API key"
consumer_secret = "Secret key"
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

#Access Token
access_token = "Access Token"
access_token_secret = "Access Token Secret"
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

#Twitter API
api= tweepy.API(auth)
location = "%s,%s,%s" % ("35.95","128.25","1000km")
keyword = ""
wfile = open(os.getcwd()+"/twitter.txt",mode='w')
cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                   q=keyword,
                   since='2015-01-01',
                   count=100,
                   geocode=location,
                   include_entities=True)

for i,tweet in enumerate(cursor.items()):
print("{}:{}".format(i,tweet.text))
wfile.wrtie(tweet.text+'\n')
wfile.close()
```

Question 1.

In this case, the tweets are from '2015-01-01', but is it possible to assign date like '2015-01-01 ~ 2015-12-31' ?

Question 2.

Counts are 100 which means it will gather 100 tweets from 2015-01-01. but is there any specific gathering method I can give? Such as 100 random tweets regardless of chronological orders or 100 tweets from 2015-01-01 that have been re-tweeted most

Question 3.

In this code, tweets and tags are only things I can know. Is there way to find out location information of tweets? Latitude and longitude of where it has been uploaded?

Question 4. 
How can I get only the hashtags? not the whole tweets

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *since* and *until* operator.

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&inc‌​lude_rts=true&screen_name=your_screen_name&since:2011-05-16&until:2011-08-16
```

But it will do you little good because tweets are searchable in a small time window. To get around this check out several resources

[copied from](https://twittercommunity.com/t/search-query-with-since-and-until-return-no-rresults-but-twitter-com-search-does-whys-that/32269)